# give an example of an open subset whose closure is the set of real numbers

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is there an example of an open subset whose closure is the set of real numbers in metric spaces?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ itself?  $\mathbb R-\{0\}$?

Comment: A less trivial example is $\{x\in\mathbb R\;|\; x-\lfloor x\rfloor\notin C\}$ where $C$ is the Cantor set on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n = 0}^{\infty}((-n-1,-n) \cup (n, n+ 1))=\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Z}$ is clearly open and $\operatorname{cl} ({\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Z}}) =\mathbb{R}$ where $\operatorname{cl} $ denotes the closure.